# Visa response for Non-EEA family member of an EEA citizen

Tags: visa, ireland, pakistani-citizen

I am a British citizen who moved to the Republic of Ireland and trying to bring my mother to Ireland to live with me who is a Pakistani national. I applied for my mother's visa on her behalf on the 21st February and now it has been nearly 4 months and I still have not recieved any response of the decision which I check it every Tuesday online:

http://www.inis.gov.ie/en/INIS/Pages/Visa%20Decisions

I did contact the visamail@justice.ie and they simply responded with similar to what is already written on their website:

> The application referred to is currently awaiting examination.
>
> Due to the large volume of applications of this type, the visa office is
> currently experiencing some delays in the processing of applications.
> While every effort is made to process these applications as soon as
> possible, processing times will vary, having regard to the volume of
> applications, their complexity, the possible need for the visa office to
> seek further information in relation to certain applications, and the
> resources available.

I would like to know if that long wait is actually normal and if so, what is the maximum time wait that can be expected? My mother and I are both separated since nearly 4 months now and she is all alone at a old peoples care home and I really miss her and need her to be with me in Ireland instead.

Stupid question but is there anything else I can do to speed up the process?

Comment: You can try SOLVIT: http://ec.europa.eu/solvit/index%5Fen.htm

Comment: thanks @phoog, as per the EU law, would you know if there is a certain time limit within which the Irish authorities must give a decision to the applied visa. I am asking as one of the question on SOLVIT is: Do you believe the authority is breaching your EU rights? It has been nearly 4 months and the Irish authority wouldn't be exactly breaching my EU rights if the time limit of Irish authority to respond with a decision is for example 6 months as per EU law.

Comment: It's supposed to be granted within a couple of weeks, "on the basis of an accelerated procedure" or something like that.

Comment: Maybe you should wait until it's 6 months from the date you submitted the application?... On http://www.inis.gov.ie (http://www.inis.gov.ie/en/INIS/Pages/Current_Processing_Times) it says " If your sponsor in Ireland is an Irish/EU citizen,

We aim to process your application within 6 months after we receive all your necessary documents.
" So if also the Irish citizens have the same timeline why should you worry? .. I suggest you to have patience!

Comment: I checked for decision online today but still decision has not been given yet. Next week on the 21st August, it will be 6 months since the submission of the visa application. I will then check again day after for the visa decision as it is updated every Tuesday. If there is no response, what shall I do? This is really frustrating and keeping me worried day and night! I can't sleep thinking of my mother being all lonely without her son! Every time I ring her, she asks me to take her with me. My apologies Sayed A. for not having patience.


Shall I submit application through SOLVIT, phoog?